# Sitecore 10.0.1 containers unstable on localhost

Tags: docker

I am new to Sitecore / new to docker.  I am working on a Sitecore 10.0.1 project using docker containers. The docker containers frequently do not start. I have 32 gig ram.

docker-compose up -d
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

```
Creating network "myproject-sitecore_default" with the default driver
Creating myproject-sitecore_mssql_1 ... done
Creating myproject-sitecore_solr_1  ... done
Creating myproject-sitecore_id_1       ... done
Creating myproject-sitecore_xconnect_1 ... done
Creating myproject-sitecore_cm_1       ... done
Creating myproject-sitecore_xdbautomationworker_1    ... done
Creating myproject-sitecore_cortexprocessingworker_1 ... done

ERROR: for xdbsearchworker  Container "3268bdea82eb" is unhealthy.

ERROR: for traefik  Container "d6f40402916c" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Is there a way to make the docker containers work more reliably?

Comment: What isolation are you running?

Comment: TRAEFIK_ISOLATION=hyperv
ISOLATION=default

Comment: My first stop would be to change ISOLATION to hyperv